# Unable to get property 'forEach' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Getting error for each statement and want to display data in API into table so appended in table but not working

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.get("https://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=<my API key>", function(matchdata) {
    matchdata.data.forEach(function(md) {
      console.log(md.description + " - to grab more details, simply use the unique_id " + md.unique_id + " with the cricketScore api!");
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
      return true;

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `matchdata.data` is undefined or null. Did you try logging `matchdata`?

Comment: `matchdata.matches.forEach(function(md) {..})`  use something called `debug`

Comment: You probably shouldn't post API keys here.

Comment: check link live.cricskill.com/fiddle1.html

Comment: Did you see my comment? that's the solution

Comment: live.cricskill.com/fiddle.html   I am getting data but unable to add in table

Comment: did that but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I examined data from the API endpoint you have given.

It's an object that contains data with the key `matches`.

Therefore, you should access it with the key `matches`.

```js
$.get("https://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=yourapikey", function(matchdata) {
  console.log(matchdata.matches);
    matchdata.matches.forEach(function(md) {
        console.log(md.description + " - to grab more details, simply use the unique_id " + md.unique_id + " with the cricketScore api!");
               $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");                
              return true;              

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you use your apikey?

Comment: Yes Check on the link www.live.cricskill.com/fiddle1.html

Comment: @Ankit I added the api key. Can you try running it? `tblRow` is not defined here, but `map` works.

Comment: Not working added  can you plz share sample html were you just call data as this is way out of me i did that not coming you can check the link i have uploaded ie.  Live.cricskill.com/fiddle1.html

Comment: Please help me out i m new to this not getting wat to do

Comment: Where are you defining `tblRow` variable? Did you mean `$('tblRow')`, `$('.tblRow')`, or `$('#tblRow')`?

Comment: @Ankit please make sure you&#39;re selecting `tblRow` correctly. See my previous comment.